# How to change the event calendar event details dynamically on rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, calendar

I'm using [event calendar](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar) on my rails project (rails 2.3.8) and I need to add feature that allows to users to pick value from drop down menu and according to that things which have loaded on event should be change. (Normally in event calendar it shows event name on the events). Please can some one give me a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a answer for this problem and we can do that by passing parameters on **event_strips_for_month** method

**app/controllers/calendar_controller.rb**

```
@event_strips = Event.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month, :include => :some_relation, :conditions => 'some_relations.some_column = true')
```

This might be helpful for another new comer to learn about event calendar. Thanks